# cannot open Andoid emulator on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emulation

I am using the [`github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator`](https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator) extension for VS Code. Whenever I try to open the emulator, I get these notifications. what is the problem and what should I do about it?

1. > Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators! Make sure your path is correct. Try running this command in your terminal: "false\emulator" -list-avds
   > source: Android iOS emulator (extension)
2. > Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
   > source: Android iOS emulator (extension)
3. > Make sure your Windows path is set correctly! Example: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
   > source: Android iOS emulator (extension)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows remove .exe from the path
New path should be: :\Users\HUNG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

Comment: and how/where you can remove that part?

Answer (score 0):

See this GitHub issue ticket in the `DiemasMichiels/emulator` extension's repo: [Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators #14](https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator/issues/14)

Quoting from some of the comments in the discussion thread there:

https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator/issues/14#issuecomment-464050318 :

> This is related to my update with #13. Point it to the directory instead of the actual executable file instead and I think it should work just fine! - [antonholmberg](https://github.com/antonholmberg)

https://github.com/DiemasMichiels/emulator/issues/14#issuecomment-464254880 :

> In previous version (0.0.7) it works with:
> `"emulator.emulatorPath": "%ANDROID_HOME%/emulator/emulator.exe"`
> But now (1.0.0): Only works when i use absolute path like:
> `"emulator.emulatorPath": "C:\Users\RodrigoSaka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator"` - [RodrigoSaka](https://github.com/RodrigoSaka)

Given those comments, you should update your settings.json with something like this, where you give the absolute path to the directory *containing* the emulator executable instead of the path to the executable:

```json
"emulator.emulatorPath": "C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator"
```