# Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators! Make sure your path is correct VS Code

Tags: android, flutter

I download Android Studio but I am using VS Code. I want to learn flutter so I download Android IOS Emulator extension for using emulator. But when I click View Android Emulators there are two exceptions.
The first one is:

Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators! Make sure your path is correct. Try running this command in your terminal: "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator" -list-avds

The second one is:
Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

When I check my path it is correct. I am sure about it. My username has non-ASCII characters. Could the problem be caused by this?
[These are my problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEEPE.jpg)How can I fix this. I am trying to solve this problem for 3 days.

When I try to open emulator in Android Studio. There is this exception.

PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: The path where you covered, got a `?` before `e`, check if this character a `special character`. Try to edit your username, and try again.

Comment: @iwpz is right. I assume that your username is "Çelik". You need to change this to "celik".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746209/cannot-open-emulator-on-vs-code