# Vscode wont run my Android Emmulator why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Something went wrong fetching you Android emulators! Make sure your path is correct. Try running this command in your terminal: "false\emulator" -list-avds

i try to search in google but theres no help i found

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746209/cannot-open-emulator-on-vs-code

Comment: If any of the answers [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746209/cannot-open-emulator-on-vs-code) solve your problem, give them an upvote :)